# Named process internal mutexes with C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

Are there ways to implement named process internal mutexes using C/C++ (in Unix/Linux)?

The trick is that the mutexes lifetime  would need to be process persistent. Unlike for example the named posix semaphores and shared memory.

You could have for example pthread mutexes, in a dynamic map and access them with some id. But then you need to protect the mutexes somehow.

If you use memory mapped files or shared memory, you get the filesystem persistence...

Any ideas?

Comment: A mutex is often noted as a binary semaphore, you don't need anything more.

Comment: Do you want to name the mutexes at compile- or at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

You can always revert back to the older (albeit depreciated) System V semaphores which work off a common key-value rather than a POSIX named semaphore which has file-system persistence.  That being said, a POSIX named semaphore will not have file-system persistence if you close and then unlink the semaphore in every process using it.  Once the last process that was using the semaphore has exited, the semaphore reference will be removed from the file-system.  If you're worried about the visibility of the semaphore at the file-system level, you can always precede the name of the semaphore with a "." in order to make the file invisible, and/or adjust the permissions on the file so that only the current user or some privileged user/group can access the semaphore.

Comment: To use sem_unlink you would need to know that no other user will anymore wan't to get access to the named semaphore. From sem_unlink documentation:
"Calls to sem_open() to re-create or re-connect to the semaphore refer to a new semaphore after sem_unlink() is called"

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "process-persistent"? If you want them to persist after the process ends, just use named semaphores or named shared memory, and prefix the name with something unique to your program. If you want them to go out of existence when the process terminates, just use any kind of hash map protected by an rwlock (locked in read mode to lookup existing names, write mode to add/remove names).

Comment: By "process-persistent" I mean exactly that I wan't them to go out of existence when the process terminates.

Comment: @enomem But what is the significance of having them named, if you only need to access them within one program ? You could just create  e.g. a hash table to retreive the mutexes by name within your program

Comment: @nos: Actually C has an even easier mechanism for that: `extern` variable names... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple. Have a mapping of strings to mutexes, and a mutex to protect this mapping:

```
std::map<std::string, pthread_mutex_t *> mutexMap;
pthread_mutex_t mutexMap_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

When you need to find a mutex, take the `mutexMap_lock` lock first. Once you have the mutex, drop the lock, and cache the mutex pointer so you don't have to keep referring to this `mutexMap` point of contention.

Comment: Yes, this is the kind of solution I was also referring. But then all threads still need to lock the same lock protecting the dynamic mutex "pool". And then the unnecessary locking "bottleneck" is just moved to another place. Of course this is propably more effiecent as the "mutexMap_lock" is only held very briefly...